# issue using dynamic blocks with aws security group resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm facing issue using dynamic blocks with `aws_securtiy_group` resource. Below is the json file containing the ports & description.

```json
{
  "Ports": [
    {
      "FromPort": 22,
      "ToPort": 22,
      "Description": "Allow ssh connection"
    },
    {
      "FromPort": 8443,
      "ToPort": 8443,
      "Description": "Allow https connection"
    },
    {
      "FromPort": 443,
      "ToPort": 443,
      "Description": "Allow http connection"
    }
  ]
}
```

Below is the Terraform code

```
locals {
  config_ports = jsondecode(file("ports.json"))
  rule_name    = keys(local.config_ports)
  ports_config = tomap(merge([
    for rules, v in local.config_ports : {
      for i, ports in v : "${rules}${i}" => {
        fromport    = ports.FromPort
        toport      = ports.ToPort
        description = ports.Description
      }
    }
  ]...))
}

resource "aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list" "pl-rules" {
  for_each       = { for idx, rule_names in local.rules_names : rule_names => idx }
  name           = "pl-${each.key}"
  address_family = "IPv4"
  max_entries    = 7
}

resource "aws_security_group" "using-pl" {
  name            = "using-pl"
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.testing.id
  protocol        = "tcp"
  prefix_list_ids = [for v in aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.pl-rules : v.id]

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.config_ports
    content {
      description = ingress.value.Description
      from_port   = ingress.value.FromPort
      to_port     = ingress.value.ToPort
    }
  }
}
```

I'm seeing the error message as
╷
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│
│   on main.tf line 123, in resource "aws_security_group" "using-pl":
│  123:   protocol        = "tcp"
│
│ An argument named "protocol" is not expected here.
╵

Please help me point out where the issue is. When I try to create individual resources without `dynamic` block it works without issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check TF docs for [aws_security_group](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/security_group), you will find that indeed there is no such argument as `protocol`. Instead it should be in the dynamic block:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "using-pl" {
  name            = "using-pl"
  vpc_id          = aws_vpc.testing.id
 
  prefix_list_ids = [for v in aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.pl-rules : v.id]

  dynamic "ingress" {
    for_each = local.config_ports
    content {
      description = ingress.value.Description
      from_port   = ingress.value.FromPort
      to_port     = ingress.value.ToPort
      protocol    = "tcp"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @Marcin for the reply. I below error with suggested method.

│ Error: Unsupported argument
││   on main.tf line 116, in resource "aws_security_group" "using-pl":
│  116:   prefix_list_ids = [for v in aws_ec2_managed_prefix_list.pl-rules : v.id]
│
│ An argument named "prefix_list_ids" is not expected here.
│ Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on main.tf line 121, in resource "aws_security_group" "using-pl":
│  121:       description = ingress.value.Description
│     ├────────────────
│     │ ingress.value is tuple with 3 elements
││ This value does not have any attributes

Comment: @surya This is a new issue, so please make new question.

Comment: noted @Marcin, will raise a new question thank you

Comment: @surya My current answer solves the original problem that you reported.